# How to take element from collection by specific class name using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to make a slider control using jQuery. In each slide you can have a content like images, paragraphs and so on.

```
<div class="slide first current">
    <h1>Ninja Superman slide</h1>
    <p>Here's some text.</p>
    <img src="http://blogs.telerik.com/images/default-source/miroslav-miroslav/super_ninja.png?sfvrsn=2" width="300" height="300">
</div>
<div class="slide">
    <h1> Ninja Samurai</h1>
    <p>Here's some text about ninja samurais</p>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRVNH4RuAsomFkrv9tWiz_VBaCbVSWbC7gDXtOag9e7K_JHuC6zZR5Es-Y" width="500" height="300">
</div>

<div class="slide last">
    <h1>The birth of a ninja</h1>
    <p>Some text about the birth of a ninja from egg.</p>
    <img src="http://forums.academy.telerik.com/?qa=blob&qa_blobid=5564423925526764256" width="300" height="300">
</div>
```

I have 2 buttons for previous and next slide.

```
<input type="button" id="prev-btn" value="Previous slide" />
<input type="button" id="next-btn" value="Next slide" />
```

On each div (slide content) I have a class "slide", so I can locate is as a slide. I'm made a collection by taking all the elements from document with class "slide".

```
var $slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
```

Now I have to make a function onNextButtonClick(), that will change my slides. But I don't know how to take the current slide. I have a class "current", given on first element by default. So my question is: how to take an element from collection with specific attribute. Something like that:

```
var $currentSlide = $slides[element.class == "current"];
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery why use getElementsByClassName. Also find it weird to assign the result to $slides as the $ would make you think an jquery instance is stored there. var $slides = $("slide"); is much better and then use var $current; $slides.each(function() { if ($(this).is(".current")) { $current = $(this); }});

Comment: Could you not select the slides: `var $slides = $(".slide");` which puts them in an array and you can select them as such: `$slides[0]` would be the first slide

Comment: @Last1Here what if the first slide isn't the current slide?

Comment: `var $currentslides = $(".slide.current");` or `var $slides = $(".slide");var $currentslides = $slides.filter(".current");`

Comment: Yes, I have to check it each time when I press the next button, so I have to check which of the element has a class "current".

Answer (score 1):

Since you use jQuery, I think you better should use jQuery selector to select element.
You can select element with several class by:

```
var $slides = $(".slide.current");
```

You can find out infomation about how to choose element according to class, attribute or state  here
[enter link description here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

If the elements with the class `current` are child nodes of `$slides`, the following code will select them all:

```
$('.current', $slides)
```

The second parameter to the call of the `$` function is the scope for the selector.

If you want to get the first element of all the matched elements, you can do this as follows:

```
$('.current', $slides)[0]
```

[You can see a demonstration here.](http://jsbin.com/sesomoya/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Best to use the jQuery/sizzle selectors.

```
var $slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
```

becomes

```
var $slides = $(".slide");

var $currentSlide = $slides.filter(".current");
```

Comment: where is your answer about getting the current slide?

Comment: Find will search in the descendants.  `current` is not descendants thus you need to use `.filter()` in short `$slides.find(".current")` will never work

Comment: @Satpal -- Thanks. Brain fart.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher, Please don't use slangs.

Answer (score 0):

To select the current slide you can use

```
$(".current")
```

also, you can try out jQuery orbit if you want a simple way to make a slider
http://zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider

Answer (score 0):

You can add class to the buttons to get the click event

```
<input class="next-prev-btn" type="button" id="prev-btn" value="Previous slide" />
<input class="next-prev-btn" type="button" id="next-btn" value="Next slide" />
```

After that get the click event

```
$(".next-prev-btn").on('click',function(){
    // get the clicked button's id
    var clickedButton = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.slide').each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('current'))
        {           
           // here you will get the div which have current class 
           // your business logic 

           // you can get your clicked button also by
           if(clickedButton=='prev-btn')
           {
                // your logic for previous button click
           }
           else
           {
                // your logic for next button click
           }

           // if you are done with your functionality you can break the look here to prevent unwanted execution through the loop
           break;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you should use a toggle(); ?

Use jQuery! Add to head:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp

Working on jQuery is more easy and faster.

Comment: this doesn't give the correct info to the user. Where is your answer concerning getting the current slide?

Comment: Sorry, it isnt appropriate solution. Perhaps he should use toggle() to add and remove classes "current" ?

Comment: @komon, Never guess give answer when you know its correct

Comment: by just saying he has to use a function without explanation is not enough